# Console.log() Inside Fetch Function Not Logging Data

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing an issue with my fetch function. It seems that it successfully fetches data from the specified endpoint and re-renders the element as expected. However, the problem is that the console.log() statement inside the fetch function doesn't display anything.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/64e453b48e4aa6225ed39a01", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'X-Master-Key': '$2b$10$WZHPQG51v2vHUWcuzB5bY.QCdFiNwtMdzURgC/En6o6ywX0OyESim'
      }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Data from API:", data);
        this.setState({ floors: data.record });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Hi, your code seems working and it is correct: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-class-based-component-react-forked-ysvzry?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @samnoon ,i have seen that it is working on codesandbox but in my browser i can't see any things.One more things, i can 't see any console output in my browser.
i write console.log in several files of my react app but it dosen't help

Comment: @samnoon ,i checked  in my chrom browser i can't see any things but it works on Brave browser.This is somethings about chrom but still i cant find it

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing with the console.log() statement inside your fetch function not displaying anything might be related to the way you're trying to log the data. The code you provided seems correct in terms of fetching data from an API and updating the component's state. If the data is successfully fetched and the component is being re-rendered as expected, the problem could be related to the environment where you're trying to view the console output.

Here are a few troubleshooting steps to consider:

- Check the Browser Console: Ensure that you are looking at the browser's console (e.g., Chrome DevTools or Firefox Developer Tools) to see the console.log() output. This is where the log messages should appear when the code is running in a browser environment.
- Network Requests: Verify that the network request is being made by looking at the "Network" tab in your browser's developer tools. Confirm that the request is successful, and the expected data is being returned by the API.
- Error Handling: Check if any errors are being caught by the .catch() block. If there are errors, they should be logged to the console, and you should see the "Error fetching data" message.
- Component Rendering: Ensure that the component that contains this componentDidMount method is rendering correctly and that it is being mounted in your application. If the component isn't mounted, the componentDidMount method won't be executed.
- React Version: If you are using a specific version of React, make sure that it supports lifecycle methods like componentDidMount. In modern React (e.g., React 16.3+), you might use the useEffect hook instead of componentDidMount in functional components.
- Logging Environment: Double-check that you are looking at the correct console for the environment where your application is running. If you are developing in a local development server, make sure you are viewing the console for that server.

If you have verified the above points and are still not seeing the console.log() output, it's possible that there may be an issue specific to your development environment or configuration. In most cases, the logs should appear in the browser console when the code runs in a browser environment.